# Retrieving all hosted models from the tensorflow api

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

Based on the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/api_rest) for the api - it seems you can only query a known model for information.

I was hoping to query tensorflow serving for all known models.

Something like `GET http://host:port/v1/models`

Does anyone know if this is possible but un-documented?

Answer (score 1):

This is not (yet) possible.

Part of the reason this is not implemented on the REST side, is to maintain parity with gRPC API. Once we add support for listing all models, it will be made available to both gRPC and REST endpoints.

Comment: is there an ETA for this?

Comment: It's been a few months but I can't see anything online about this - any news?